# Save changing variables for promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am using promises for my database access (elasticsearchjs, which uses [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)).

For each ID in my list im am starting a new query. Now I want to know the ID of the element when the query fails.

```
var idList = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', '...'];
var promises = [];

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {

  // dbQueryFunction returns a promise object
  promises.push(dbQueryFunction(idList[i])
    .then(function(data) {
        // Do stuff...
    })
    .error(function(errorMessage) {
      console.log('[ERROR] id: ' + id); //<== Print ID here
    })
  );
}

// Wait for all promises to be resolved
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Everything is done!');
  });
```

How can I save additional information in my Promises? I tried using `Promise.bind()` but could not get it working.

Edit:

To clarify about the 'size' variable: This was a snippet where I wanted the results of the first n elements. So size is equals or smaller than my array size.

Comment: What are you rejecting the promise with (that is, what's causing them to error)?

Comment: Is what you're trying to do retry by any chance?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I get a timeout error for a vew entries. I want to know the entries where the timeout error happens to further investigate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution would be this:

```
var promises = idList.map(function(id){
    return dbQueryFunction(id)
    .then(function(data) {
        // Do stuff...
    })
    .error(function(errorMessage) {
      console.log('[ERROR] id: ' + id); 
    });
});
```

(if the `size` variable doesn't hold the size of the array, use `idList.slice(0,size)` instead of `idList`).

Note about `bind`: it could, maybe, be usable here (add `.bind(idList[i])` and then log `this`) but the problem is you don't create (and therefore don't own) the promise object. What if the querying library depends on a specific context ?

Comment: But that ignores the `size` constraint.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I assumed this was the size of the array. I edited.

Comment: Also `dbQueryFunction(idList[i])` should be `dbQueryFunction(id)` I believe

Comment: You probably want to use `Promise.map` here which'd give OP a chance to hook on them being done (instead of `Promise.all` in their code)

Comment: Ivan Nevostruev ---dbQueryFunction(idList[i]) is passing the id at index [ i ]

Comment: To clarify about my size variable: This was a snippet where I wanted the results of the first n elements. So size is equals or smaller than my array size.

Comment: I tried this and it solves my problem. Very nice solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var idList = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', '...'];
var promises = [];

 // Could you do this?
   promises.push(dbQueryFunction(idList[i])
     .then(function(data) {
       // Do stuff...
       idList.deleteID(idList[(promises.length - 1) || 0]);
       // Or something to remove the successful ids from the list
       // leaving you with the idList of the unsuccessful ids
     })
     .error(function(errorMessage) {
        console.log('[ERROR] id: ' + idList[0]); //<== Print ID here
     })
  );

Array.prototype.deleteID = function(array,id){
   array.forEach(function(el,indx,arr){
      if(el == id){
         arr.splice(indx,1);
      }
   });
};
```